# Git Submodule PR flow

Tags: git

I have branch A in super module, as well as branch A in submodule.

I created new feature branch B from A. I had changes in submodule too, so created a new branch B in submodule as well.

I after changes I raised a PR to merge super module from B to A and submodule from B to A.

My submodule B to A got approved and merged. Now do I need to do first update my main super module PR? I always get confuse here. What would be flow from here?